# Generate lower case tag names with Oracle DBMS_XMLGEN?

Tags: oracle, plsql, xml

I am generating XML in Oracle PL/SQL with the [DBMS_XMLGEN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1012053) package:

```
OPEN base_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM foo;
base_context := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(base_cursor);
base_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(base_context, dbms_xmlgen.none);
```

My problem is that whatever I do I always get the tag names in upper case. To maintain compatibility with things further downstream, I need them to be in lower case. Is there any way I can fix this?

I know there is an option for this in [DBMS_XMLQUERY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmlque.htm), but the docs says it is not recommended to use that package.

Comment: Doc says whenever possible use DBMS _XMLGEN. If not you can use the DBMS_XMLQUERY as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ORACLE-BASE,

> Where possible DBMS_XMLGEN should be used as it is more efficient than using the Java based DBMS_XMLQUERY

And:

> The example below is a copy of the previous code with all references to DBMS_XMLQUERY replaced by references to DBMS_XMLGEN. Note that two of the lines have been commented out as ***this functionality is currently not present in DBMS_XMLGEN***

I added my emphasis, because this refers specifically to the `settagcase` you are looking for.

> ```
> --DBMS_XMLGEN.settagcase(v_ctx, DBMS_XMLGen.LOWER_CASE);
> ```

So it looks like you are stuck with the slower DBMS_XMLQUERY.